# How to find tail node of a singly linked list without having to traverse the list?

Tags: count, tail, singly-linked-list

I'm thinking it's probably possible if i have a count variable that keeps track of the # of records in the list, but even then i can't just jump to the element[count] to the tail just like in the array.

This really befuddling me, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One thought is to keep track of a tail pointer as you build the linked list. The other way is to allow building the linked list only by inserting nodes at the beginning, this way you can keep track of tail.